# Using jdbc properties file to set dataSource in applicatioinContext.xml.Why I must use ${jdbc.XXX} but not ${XXX}?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, properties, spring-jdbc

I am training to integrate the Struts2 and Spring and Hibernate.I using a properties file to set the dataSource:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db.properties"/>
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
  <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClass}" />
  <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
  <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
  <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>
```

And this is the db.properties following:

```
jdbc.driverClass=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc\:mysql\://localhost\:3306/sp3
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=123456
```

I find the example about this in spring-reference,but **I just don't know why I must use ${jdbc.XXXXX} but not ${XXXXX}.I try to write "username=root","password=123456",and then it cause "Access denied for user 'Administrator'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"**

If using the Expression Language principle:${jdbc.username} meanings "getJdbc().getUsername();"because in the struts-tag,${model} means getModel(),is it right?

I find the source about PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and ComboPooledDataSource ,but I can not find any code about getJdbc();

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you're asking. `jdbc.username` is just a text, or a key if you want. You could have used "BLABLABLA=root" in `db.properties` and in your xml `<property name="user" value="${BLABLABLA}" />`.

Probably you are confusing `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` with [PropertyOverrideConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-overrideconfigurer).

Comment: It's my fail.My question is:when I use jdbc.driverClass = ....,everything is ok,but I try to change the key to driverClass,it will cause an Exception "Access denied for user 'Administrator'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Answer (score 0):

If you had the problems with your properties, you would have got an exception something like->

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'XYZ' in string value "${XYZ}".

What do you mean by 'everything is ok'? Were you able to access DB with previous setup?

The exception you are getting seems related to username and password combination OR you don;t have proper rights/GRANTS.

Answer (score 0):

jdbc.XXXXX is just a key in the property file. You could have used  anything in place of it.When you perform  ${something} it would just pick the value for key  'something' from the property file and use it for populating the properties of bean. 
For example : 
`<property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />` is just setting the value for a field named 'jdbcUrl' in class  ComboPooledDataSource.